# How to playing full screen youtube video in Android webview?

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I'm new in android developer. I have 2 questions :

1. How to make full screen video immediately after tapping play sign?
2. When the video in normal size and user want to scroll the page which is having header    and in static mode, the video will cover the header. It should be below the header when user scroll it until the header. How to make the video below the header when user scroll the page until header position?

This is my Code :

```
        String widthAndHeight = "width='220' height='200'";
        String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/AyeJyctGhSc&feature=youtube_gdata";

        String temp = "<object "+widthAndHeight+">" +
        "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>" +
        "</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>" +
        "</param><embed src='"+ videoURL +"'" +
        " type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'" + widthAndHeight +
        "></embed></object>";

        video.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        video.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        video.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        video.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        video.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        video.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        video.loadData(temp,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Did that work for you ever?

Answer (score 2):

Use this source to play Youtube Video

```
        String video = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
                + youtubeId +
                "?autoplay=1"
                + "&fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
                + "</iframe>\n";
        mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setInitialScale(0);
        mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebview.loadData(video,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html"   width=100% height=100% src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YjMSttRJrhA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"   frameborder="0" allowFullScreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your Activity :

```
WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            customComponenet.addView(view);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            if (customComponenet == null)
                return;
            // Hide the custom view.
            customComponenet.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

where customComponent is your FrameLayout.

Comment: Old answer, but anyway, please add more details

Answer (score 0):

To play a youtube video

you have to parse the url and play the video in videoview